# Regex for date and numeric values without quotes

Tags: json, regex

I have a long JSON with around 40K lines(similar to below), I need a regex exp so that I could find & replace all double quoted numeric values with normal numeric values.

This is the example of input:

```
"date": "5/9/2026",
"cost": 33,300,000.45",
"insured": "33,295,198.12",
```

Expected Output:

```
"date": 5/9/2026,
"cost": 33,300,000.45,
"insured": 33,295,198.12,
```

I googled on stackoverflow, followed respective soultions but didn't match my expected output.

My Try : `"([0-9]*\,[0-9]*\,[0-9]*\,.[0-9])"`

Comment: If you do that, the JSON will become invalid since `5/9/2026` or `33,300,000.45` are not numeric values.

Comment: "([0-9]\/[0-9]{2}\/[0-9]*)" - I made this for date and it worked!

Comment: read in/parse JSON, for each key-value pair try to cast the value to an int or a float, serialize the result back to JSON

Comment: sure Grisha! Suggestion appreciated :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using positive lookbehind and negative lookahead, the following regex should give you the expected output:

```
(?<=:\s)"?([0-9]{1,3}(?:\,[0-9]{3})*(?:\.\d+)?)(?!\/)"?
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/3toTIq/1)

Comment: Thankyou! This indeed worked! Also, I developed "([0-9]\/[0-9]{2}\/[0-9]*)" & 
"([0-9]*\,[0-9]{3}\,[0-9]*\.[0-9]*)" for date and numeric values respectively.

Comment: Please note that your regex for numeric values matches certain invalid values and doesn't match few valid values [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/3toTIq/2)

Answer (score 0):

After replacements it won't be valid json, if it doesn't matter for you then use this code:

```js
var str = "\"date\": \"5/9/2026\", \"cost\": \"33,300,000.45\", \"insured\": \"33,295,198.12\",";

var mapReplace = {
       ": \"":": ",
       "\",":",",
    };
    var res = str.replace(/: "|",/g,function(match){
        return mapReplace[match];
      });
      
      console.log(res);
```

Comment: Thanks for the js code! I guess I'll stick to normal regex! :)

Comment: @SanketSawant you are welcome, good luck. Also you could use just find+replace in any editor, if you need just remove bad symbols, just after that your json won't be valid. Don't know where you can use it :)) Good Luck!